# How to have align buttons on top left and right, and bottom left and right in android?

Tags: android, android-layout

I am practicing android layouts:

What I am stuck at is **how to nest LinearLayouts to have buttons at top left, top right, bottom left, and bottom right** of the activity.

I would appreciate example using LinearLayout and RelativeLayout so I can understand how to proceed.

I really am at a standstill on how to proceed.

Thank You.

Answer (score 0):

The best way would be to use a Relative layout and then a combination of [layout_alignParentBottom](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.html#attr_android%3alayout_alignParentBottom), [layout_alignParentLeft](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.html#attr_android%3alayout_alignParentLeft), [layout_alignParentRight](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.html#attr_android%3alayout_alignParentRight) and/or [layout_alignParentTop](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.html#attr_android%3alayout_alignParentTop) for each button.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I had just started to read a tutorial on MobileTuts.com regarding RelativeLayouts. But what I described above, is LinearLayout even suited for this thing? I mean, I felt that I was trying to get it do something it was not intended for.

Comment: LinearLayouts are best suited for situations when you want to align a set of widgets horizontally or vertically. Relative layouts are better suited when you want to place widgets anywhere on the screen. The page below has some pretty good explanations, click on the image to learn more about that type of layout:

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/declaring-layout.html#CommonLayouts